# How do I get basic security to apply when programmatically creating WebChannel in WCF?

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I am creating a WCF channel for a POX web client in code using the `WebChannelFactory`. I have created a binding configuration in my `app.config` with basic authentication set, but when I try to connect to the service endpoint, basic security is not being applied and I get a 401 from the server.

The name in my `app.config` endpoint configuration and my programmatic declaration match. I can confirm this b/c it's picking up the address correctly.

The service endpoint challenges for BASIC security, but nothing happens.

Do I need to set the wcf client endpointConfiguration?

**Code**

```
 namespace AccountServices
 {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IAccount
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate="?resourceId={resourceId}")]
        XmlElement GetAccount(string resourceId);
    }

    public class AccountService
    {
        public XmlElement GetAccount(string resourceId, string userName, string password)
        {
            WebChannelFactory<ICPM> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IAccount>("AccountHttpClient");

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

            IAccount proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            try
            {
                return proxy.GetAccount(resourceId);
            }
            catch (System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException securityEx)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RawWebBinding" contentTypeMapper="">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
                        realm="Login" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="pox">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://ENDPOINTADDRESS/"
            behaviorConfiguration="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawWebBinding"
            contract="AccountServices.IAccount" name="AccountHttpClient" kind=""
            endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an endpointConfiguration fixed the issue.  The authentication header is now being sent across.

```
       ...
<system.serviceModel>
        <standardEndpoints>
            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="NewStandardEndpoint0">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
                            realm="Login" />
                    </security>
                </standardEndpoint>
            </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
    ...

   <client>
        <endpoint address="https://ENDPOINTADDRESS/"
            behaviorConfiguration="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawWebBinding"
            contract="AccountServices.IAccount" name="AccountHttpClient" kind="webHttpEndpoint"
            endpointConfiguration="NewStandardEndPoint0" />
    </client>
```