# Putting a password in the authorization header using WebChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, http-headers

I'm trying to build a REST service and client and I need to send some authorization information through the HTTP request. However, the authorization header comes empty when I check it on the server.
This is the best I got on the client code:

```
WebChannelFactory<IAdminService> cf =
    new WebChannelFactory<IAdminService>(agency.Value);
cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = "passw0rd";

IAdminService channel = cf.CreateChannel();
List<Car> cars = channel.GetCars();
```

And this is the service code, trying to inspect the header, but it's empty:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "cars")]
[OperationContract]
Cars GetCars()
{
    WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
    string authHeader = ctx.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
    Console.WriteLine("authHeader={0}", authHeader);
    if (authHeader == null)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return new Cars();
    }
    return CarDatabase.Instance.GetCars();
}
```

Any help on what I'm missing will be appreciated. (There's no need for encrypting anything for now, just send "admin" and "passw0rd" over in the right place)

Comment: Seems very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7263135/246811